# Show indicator over ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm implementing ViewPager to navigate throught 3 fragments. The user should open the app and start in fragment 1, and when it's done continue to fragment 2.

To let the user know this, I'm trying to implement some kind of indication that should appear when the user is done on one fragment and must follow to the next.

For this, I decided to put an imageView with an arrow in a `GONE` initial state that should became `VISIBLE` when the user has done. This is how I have coded it:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/Black"
            android:textAppearance="@style/PagerTabStripText" />     
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>     
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in MainActivity's onCreate() I define the imageView:

```
private ImageView arrow;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    arrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrow);
    /*Make arrow gone*/
    arrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    vpAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(vpAdapter);
```

And when the user has done, I became it visible this way:

```
arrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

But I'm not getting to make it visible.

**Update**

How it looks in the xml file

[image]

**Update 2**

If I set the ImageView in the xml below the ViewPager, the app crashes and this is what logcat says.

```
09-02 17:38:52.377: E/AndroidRuntime(11832): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 17:38:52.377: E/AndroidRuntime(11832): Process: com.itest, PID: 11832
09-02 17:38:52.377: E/AndroidRuntime(11832): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.itest/com.itest.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
09-02 17:38:52.377: E/AndroidRuntime(11832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
09-02 17:38:52.377: E/AndroidRuntime(11832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
09-02 17:38:52.377: E/AndroidRuntime(11832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
09-02 17:38:52.377: E/AndroidRuntime(11832):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
09-02 17:38:52.377: E/AndroidRuntime(11832):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-02 17:38:52.377: E/AndroidRuntime(11832):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
09-02 17:38:52.377: E/AndroidRuntime(11832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
09-02 17:38:52.377: E/AndroidRuntime(11832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 17:38:52.377: E/AndroidRuntime(11832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-02 17:38:52.377: E/AndroidRuntime(11832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
09-02 17:38:52.377: E/AndroidRuntime(11832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
09-02 17:38:52.377: E/AndroidRuntime(11832):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-02 17:38:52.377: E/AndroidRuntime(11832): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
09-02 17:38:52.377: E/AndroidRuntime(11832):    at com.itest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:102)
09-02 17:38:52.377: E/AndroidRuntime(11832):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
09-02 17:38:52.377: E/AndroidRuntime(11832):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
09-02 17:38:52.377: E/AndroidRuntime(11832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
09-02 17:38:52.377: E/AndroidRuntime(11832):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: if you're sure you haven't mixed up the IDs after moving the ImageView below the ViewPager (in the XML file, no modification of your java), clean your project - it's probably just the R.java file messing up.

Comment: ataulm, The ID's are ok. I've tryed cleaning, rebuilding, closing and reopening... but nothing works

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of `main.xml` (for different configurations)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `RelativeLayout` with `FrameLayout`. `FrameLayout` leaves you put a `View` on top of another and I think your problem is that the `ViewPager` is always on top of the arrow.

**EDIT**

You can call the method `bringToFront()` for the arrow image, that will put it on top of everything. The only problem is you can move it back anymore but if you hide it that should do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking on something like that. I tryed to put the imageview under the ViewPager in the xml file but it throwed some kind of error when doing that. Let me try your way

Comment: I think this should do the trick.`ViewPager` seems to be on top of `ImageView`.

Comment: Well, I tryed to put FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout but the problem continues...

Comment: Sounds interesting, how is that method implemented?

Comment: It is actually a method inherited from the `View` class in your case just do `arrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); arrow.bringToFront()`

Comment: Carlos I don't know why, but even using this I don't get to make it visible. Everythins seems that the arrow is being hidden by the framents, but I don't understand why this isn,t working. Maybe should change order in the xml file? I've edited the onCreate method

Comment: On your xml file, can you see the arrow?

Comment: Running out of answers :P But I'd say you move the `ImageView` below the `ViewPager` on the xml file

Comment: Then I think that all answers are finished... xD have a look at the second update on the post

Comment: relative layout does support overlapping of views.

Comment: xml file is the same. To put the imageview below the viewpager I just copy the imageview code and paste it under `</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>`

Comment: Maybe clean your project? And if that doesn't work try deleting you R file

Comment: Nothing works, so I've decided to do it in another way. Anyway, as I cannot delete the question, and your answer is the one that should make this work, I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

please correct your code like this:

```
private ImageView arrow;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  arrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrow);
  /*Make arrow gone*/
  //arrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  arrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIABLE);
```

i think because of viewpager's attribute is and you set your image's visibity is gone in onCreate method.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Comment: Well, that really doesn't matter... I'm trying at this moment to make it show at the app start without making it gone or invisible, and neither I get it show. So the problem must be other

Comment: please try add "android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/arrow"" in xml file:<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"                                 android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/arrow">

Comment: The arrow must be shown at the middle left side of the screen, over the viewPager, so I can't place it outside of the viewpager

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not use [JackWharton](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/tree/master/library) viewpagerindicator.

Comment: I have had a look to that and seems to be some kind of indicator that swhows in what page you are. What i need is just to show an arrow at the middle right side of the screen only when the user finishes what must do on the first fragment, lets say, when it touches the last button

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the newly introduced TabLayout and be setting the text in tabs with the strings in bullet form. Check the complete project [here](https://medium.com/dailyrounds-engineering/simple-on-boarding-screen-in-andorid-d31f8a472f1e#.bwhzcbt6u)